# Open alert on click of bootstrap select live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

```html
<select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name = "name1" id ="id1">
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option>Option1</option>
 </select>
```

How to trigger an alert on clicking bootstrap select live search input box ?

I tried with this, but its not working.

```
$(this).closest('.bootstrap-select').find('.bs-searchbox input').on('click',function(){
    alert("live searching ..");
})
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your html as well?

Comment: I'd suggest hooking to the event handlers which the bootstrap select exposes: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events

Comment: @Kiran Shahi Added. I even tried the above snippet with id instead of this in a ready function. Still it didn't work.

Comment: @Lmnop where is your `<input>` where you want to add click event?

Comment: @Kiran Shahi. I am using bootstrap selectpicker data-live-search which is an input box.

Answer (score 1):

Here is probably the correct Solution *(probably)*:

Since the `select`-**Tag** is replace later(after the `onload` Event), so to be on the save side, so that it can be found "*better*" with a timeout.
*I replace the `alert` call to a `config.info` call.*

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  var newBox = $("#selectControl").get(0).parentNode;
       
  $(newBox).find("input").on("click",function(){
    console.info("live searching ..");
  });
  
 }, 1000);
```

```html
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/css/custom.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<div class="container">  
<div>
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="selectControl">
   <option data-tokens="Option 1">Option 1</option>
   <option data-tokens="Option 2">Option 2</option>
   <option data-tokens="Option 3">Option 3</option>
   <option data-tokens="Option 4">Option 4</option>
 </select>

</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js" >
</script>
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" >
</script>
<script src="https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js">
</script>    
        
    </body>
```

**btw.:** details to te Control can be found [in this Github](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), found it while *google*-ing

Comment: Thank you winner_joiner. But I want to add click event to live search input box which appears in bootstrap select dropdown list, not for select element